# C: Why do not get the last line of my output?

Tags: c

The question I am working on asks me to write code that prints each value from `-1` to `1` *inclusive*, incremented by a value of `0.01` to solve the mathematical function `f(x) = x^2 + 4` (to 4 decimal places).

**example:**

```
f(-1.00) = 5.0000
f(-0.99) = 4.9801
...
f(1.00) = 5.0000
```

---

**Problem:**

I do not get the last line of the code: `f(1.00) = 5.0000`. My question is how do I modify my program so that it does appear, and can you also explain why it does not appear in the first place, please?

**Code:**

Below is my code. It is printing out every value of `y` when `x` is between `0` and `1`, except for `f(1.00) = 5.0000`...

```
double numberForQ4 = -1.00; 
double valueOfY = 0; 

for ( numberForQ4 = -1.00; numberForQ4 <= 1.00; numberForQ4 += 0.01 ) { 
    valueOfY = numberForQ4 * numberForQ4 + 4; 
    printf( "f(%.2f) = %.4f \n", numberForQ4, valueOfY );
}
```

Comment: Try flushing the output buffer after the `for` loop: `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: Haven't tested, but you might be facing floating precision problem. Simply, change the `<=1.00` to something like `<=1.00+1e-6`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Code with monetary values use the number of pennies rather than fractions of a dollar for this kind of weird floating behavior. What if you tried `numberForQ4 = -100; numberForQ4 <= 100; numberForQ4++`, and divide `numberForQ4` by `100.0` for the math?

Answer (score 4):

> Why do not get the last line of my output?

Floating point math has peculiarities since `0.01` is not exactly representable as a `double` given it encodes as some *binary* fraction.  In OP's case, something just higher or lower than 0.01 and subsequent math makes for just *slightly* unexpected results.

> how do I modify my program

Instead, iterate using an integer.

```
// for ( numberForQ4 = -1.00; numberForQ4 <= 1.00; numberForQ4 += 0.01 ) { 
for ( int i = -100; i <= 100; i++ ) { 
  numberForQ4 = i/100.0;
  ...
```

---

Tip: [iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration#Computing) loops are best coded using integers.

---

> can you also explain why it does not appear in the first place, 
>   please?

Try your original code again and use enough precision to see why.

```
printf( ".01 = %.21f\n", 0.01);
for ( numberForQ4 = -1.00; numberForQ4 <= 1.00; numberForQ4 += 0.01 ) { 
    valueOfY = numberForQ4 * numberForQ4 + 4; 
    printf( "f(%.21f) = %.21f \n", numberForQ4, valueOfY );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you make this little change:

```
for ( numberForQ4 = -1.00; numberForQ4 <= 1.00; numberForQ4 += 0.01 ) { 
    valueOfY = numberForQ4 * numberForQ4 + 4; 
    printf( "f(%.20f) = %.4f \n", numberForQ4, valueOfY );
         //       ^ 20 instead of 2
}
```

You will get output like:

```
f(-1.00000000000000000000) = 5.0000 
f(-0.98999999999999999112) = 4.9801 
f(-0.97999999999999998224) = 4.9604 
f(-0.96999999999999997335) = 4.9409 
. . .
. . .
f(0.97000000000000141664) = 4.9409 
f(0.98000000000000142553) = 4.9604 
f(0.99000000000000143441) = 4.9801
```

As you can see, the rounding error of the double causes the "last" iteration to be skipped. That is: Adding `0.1` to `0.99000000000000143441` will give something greater than `1.0` causing the loop to end.

For a way to solve this, see the answer by @chux:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53736875/4386427

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you dont get the last value is about the variable type you are using (double). When you increment your index variable by 0.1 it is not as precise as you expected, You can observe that values with the code below.

```
    int main()
{
    double numberForQ4 = -1.00; 
    double valueOfY = 0; 

    for ( ; numberForQ4 <= 1.00; numberForQ4 += 0.01) {
    printf("numForQ4 =  %.5f \n", &numberForQ4);
    valueOfY = numberForQ4 * numberForQ4 + 4; 
    printf( "f(%.2f) = %.4f \n", numberForQ4, valueOfY );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you will notice the last call is made with numberForQ4= 0.98. This is why you are not able to calculate the value with 1.00.

```
When you update your code line where you initilize variables to as shown below, you will get the correct output as I did in the online compiler. 



int main()
{
    float numberForQ4 = 1.00; 
    double valueOfY = 0; 

    for ( numberForQ4 = -1.00; numberForQ4 <= 1.00; numberForQ4 += 0.0100 ) {
    printf("numForQ4 =  %.5f\n", &numberForQ4);
    valueOfY = numberForQ4 * numberForQ4 + 4; 
    printf( "f(%.2f) = %.4f \n", numberForQ4, valueOfY );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double numberForQ4 = 1.00; 
double valueOfY = 0; 

for ( numberForQ4 = -1.00; numberForQ4 <= 1.00; numberForQ4 += 0.01 ) { 
    valueOfY = numberForQ4 * numberForQ4 + 4; 
    printf( "f(%.2f) = %.4f \n", numberForQ4, valueOfY );
}
```

Im guessing you meant to put -1.00 or 0 in the assignment of numberForQ4

Comment: That doesn't really explain the problem he's having, though.  In fact, the initial value of `numberForQ4` doesn't matter anyway, because it will get set to a new intial value (-1.00) in the first iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: Well it will matter otherwise it will only loop once and print out (5.000)

Comment: Thank you for both of your help! I edited my code and changed the initial value of  numberForQ4 to -1.00. Now, my code prints all the way up to f(0.99) but not f(1.00) = 5. Do you know how to go about printing f(1.00) = 5?

Comment: change the condition to for ( numberForQ4 = -1.00; numberForQ4 < 1.01; numberForQ4 += 0.01 )

Comment: as to why that works, but <= doesnt I am actually not sure at this stage. odd

Comment: @sjdm `<= 1.00` doesn't work because the closest `double` value to 0.01 is 0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375. So you won't actually reach 1.00 exactly, but rather a number that's slightly larger.

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
double numberForQ4; 
double valueOfY = 0; 
int i=0;


for ( numberForQ4 = -1.00; i <= 200; numberForQ4 += 0.01 , i++ ) { 
    valueOfY = numberForQ4 * numberForQ4 + 4; 
    printf( "f(%.2f) = %.4f \n", numberForQ4, valueOfY );
}
```

you old loop start from 1.00 and ends on 1.00, so it will do only one iteration.
the condetion for the loop to stop is !(numberForQ4 <= 1.00), and if you start from 1.00, in the next iteration numberForQ4 will be equal 1.01 (numberForQ4 > 1.00)

you counter is not precise enough, best solution as mentioned in comments is to use integer counter.

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, I still am unable to print f(1.00) = 5.0000 with your code. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: even with float?
it works for me:
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

what compiler are you using?

Comment: you should use float not double.

Comment: Why would you want to use float instead of double?  That makes no sense.  Trying to solve floating point rounding errors by *decreasing* the precision makes no sense at all.  Bad answer.

Comment: decreasing the precision will remove erros in his case, if he is not interesting in double why to use it? he only want %.2 , float will add unwanted errors

Comment: That's ridiculous.  You're saying you want to rely on a *specific* floating point implementation whose errors result in the value coming out right (or too low) at the end.  No one should ever do that.  The right solution is to add a margin of error to termination value, as ZizizNotZis suggested.

Comment: Actually, the best way is to use an integer counter, then multiply and add on each iteration to get the desired floating point value.  That way it avoids accumulating errors on each iteration.  It's a little slower, but much more accurate.

Comment: I agree with the integer counter

Answer (score 0):

increment is 0.01 but it may not adding exactly 0.01 to numberForQ4 due to the way floating/double precision works( since 0.01 can't be sure it is float or double here since double is just more precisioin of float).

append **f** at end of the value like below, would help

```
numberForQ4 += 0.01f

for ( numberForQ4 = -1.00; numberForQ4 <= 1.00; numberForQ4 += 0.01f ) {
```

following is good read about these rounding of errors
http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C(2f)FloatingPoint.html